# .NETCore PasswordHasher.HashPassword doesn't use TUser user ,but why included in the method signature?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

[PasswordHasher.HashPassword](https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/-/blob/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/PasswordHasher.cs#L96) doesn't use TUser user, but why included in the method signature?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Because the interface [IPasswordHasher<TUser>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.ipasswordhasher-1.hashpassword?view=aspnetcore-5.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Identity_IPasswordHasher_1_HashPassword__0_System_String_) has it.

Comment: You can check this github issue: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/23720

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `PasswordHasher<TUser>` class implements the interface `IPasswordHasher<TUser>` that defines the method `string HashPassword(TUser user, string password)`. As you noticed, `PasswordHasher<TUser>.HashPassword` doesn't use the `TUser`, but another implementation could. The `PasswordHasher<TUser>.HashPassword` generates a random salt and uses it to hash the password directly, without any external data except the password. And by looking at it it seems to be a good implementation.

You could build a `MyPasswordHasher<TUser>` that has a different salt for each user AND saves the salt for the password separately from the password. In this case you would need a `TUser` object containing the salt. Some years ago on the [Security SO](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/69421/6605) it was asked if it was a good idea to calculate the hash as `hash(username + password)`... To calculate the hash like that, you would need a `TUser` object with the `username` (**we will ignore the quality of that solution here** compared to the Microsoft solution).

Another common implementation I've seen in some sites is to have a column in the User table containing the "version" of "protocol" used for hashing passwords... In this way, if the hashing is discovered to be weak, a new "protocol" can be devised, and this "version" says in which way the hash has been calculated.

So Microsoft programmers implemented the `IPasswordHasher<TUser>` interface to be compatible with this type of hashes. They  didn't implement them, but they let open the possibility.

(as a sidenote the Microsoft version of `PasswordHasher<TUser>` generates a "packed" string containing the version, infos on the key derivation function, the salt and the hash all together)

Comment: If you're using the default `PasswordHasher` implementation, what would be a reasonable thing to pass in as `TUser`?  A `true` bool?

Comment: @Jez You cannot use a `bool`. The `TUser` must be a `class`. In general you can pass `null` if you aren't using the `user`.